# outlook 2003 error message

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2003

In my outlook 2003, my messages are not going out to certain people.  My send/recieve message popup is there informing me of a problem but also a Symantec Email Proxy popup is reoccuring.  It reads: Your email message was unable to be sent because your mail server rejected the message.  550 Administrative prohibition.  My web guy fooled around with it for 10 mins and managed to get it to send to one of the ppl I couldn't send to... he then left.  The rpoblem is still there but my web guy isn't...unless I pay him to come in yet again!  Please explain how I can possibly fix this if you can.

Answer (score 0):

That's an old issue with a few solutions which may/may not work. What I would do first if I were you is to update your Symantec virus protection and then boot into safe mode and run a virus Scan.